# TypeError: Argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable in List comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list comprehension like this : `view['entries'] = [entry for entry in view['entries'] if qs in entry.get('name') or qs in entry.get('description')]`

This list comprehension is a search filter that works with the name field because it's a required field that is never empty.
But when I search for description, I got the error `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Description field can be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in doubt, you can always just provide an empty string default value:

```
if qs in entry.get('name', '') or qs in entry.get('description', ''):
```

If the keys can be actually present with value `None`, you can do:

```
if qs in (entry.get('name') or '') or qs in (entry.get('description') or ''):
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The second example works!